# Files related list on force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, permissions, files

I have a related list of files "AttachedContentDocuments" on a VF page (using the  tag), which is accessed through a force.com site. This page works as expected for the logged in user. But when accessed over the site (i.e: for a guest user) it returns the "Authorization Required" error page.

I am aware that this typically occurs because of a permission issue. But I am unable to locate the permission required for this to work.

Waiting for suggestions.

Comment: By default, Site guest user doesn't have access to Content.  [See this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cOZcQAM).
But this answer might help you: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196553/public-guest-user-cant-access-contentdocuments/228505#228505

Answer (score 0):

In Setup:
User Interface > Sites and Domains > Sites (or type "Sites" in the search box)
Click the Site you want to configure.
On the top is the Public Access Settings button. Click that.
That takes you to the profile configuration page for the guest user accessing your site. From here you might want to try Object Settings > Files and check the permissions there.
Also, sometimes you need to allow read/write privileges on the object related to the files you want the user to be able to view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I have given the mentioned permissions already and this still gives me the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried View All on the parent object?

Comment: Yes of course. This still does not work.